# Azure B2C - SAML - The service provider is not a valid audience of the assertion

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I set up a SAML Provider for Azure B2C (Single Sign On). The IDP is happy and sends a SAML Assertion back, but Azure B2C complains.

It looks like Azure B2C cannot process the SAML Answer. The Error Message extracted via AppInsights is simple "The service provider is not a valid audience of the assertion".

The URLs seem to fit, but im not sure if the AudienceRestriction should point to the base policy or maybe the sign-in policy, as teh metadata can only be accessed via the SIGN-UP Policy as part of the URL and not the BASE:
"https://{my-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN/samlp/metadata?idptp={IDP-NAME}-SAML2"

Configuration (**updated according to the comments of this question**).

Configuration

```
              <EntityDescriptor 
              xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" 
              ID="https://{IDP-URL}/saml/2.0/idp/"
              entityID="https://{IDP-URL}/saml/2.0/idp/"
              validUntil="2099-12-31T23:59:59Z">
              <SPSSODescriptor 
              AuthnRequestsSigned="false"
              WantAssertionsSigned="false"
              ResponsesSigned="false"
              protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
                    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
                    <AssertionConsumerService 
                      index="0" 
                      isDefault="true" 
                      Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
                      Location="https://{my-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer" />
                </SPSSODescriptor>
                <IDPSSODescriptor 
                  WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" 
                  protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">                     
                    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
                    <SingleSignOnService 
                      Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                      Location="https://{IDP-URL}/saml/2.0/idp/" />               
                </IDPSSODescriptor>
            </EntityDescriptor>
```

SAML Response

```
<saml2p:Response Destination="https://{my-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer"
                 ID="Response_6793aae6a9cc629a6be69a270731961695dad50e"
                 InResponseTo="_719e3407-dbad-4761-8e8a-7e7272b2a67b"
                 IssueInstant="2022-08-17T08:34:29.112Z"
                 Version="2.0"
                 xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 >
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://{IDP-URL}/saml/2.0/idp/</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion ID="Assertion_16dc5f9b7c67ed241c79436c20296a2fd514ea87"
                     IssueInstant="2022-08-17T08:34:29.111Z"
                     Version="2.0"
                     xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     >
        <saml2:Issuer>https://{IDP-URL}/saml/2.0/idp/</saml2:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                <ds:Reference URI="#Assertion_16dc5f9b7c67ed241c79436c20296a2fd514ea87">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="xs"
                                                    xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                                    />
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                    <ds:DigestValue>/4OAX07/scGvFyDCT3BBzlHJQ7q65Ak0uGlTvE0z904=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>{removed}</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>{removed}</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">71747</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_719e3407-dbad-4761-8e8a-7e7272b2a67b"
                                               NotOnOrAfter="2022-08-17T08:34:39.112Z"
                                               Recipient="https://{my-tenant-name}/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer"
                                               />
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2022-08-17T08:34:29.111Z"
                          NotOnOrAfter="2022-08-17T08:34:59.111Z"
                          >
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>https://{my-tenant-name}/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2022-08-17T08:34:29.111Z"
                              SessionNotOnOrAfter="2022-08-17T10:34:29.111Z"
                              >
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
```

My SAML METADATA

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="_7865bef4-f0d2-4062-9e58-a145e1beb91f" entityID="https://{my-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase">
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<Reference URI="#_7865bef4-f0d2-4062-9e58-a145e1beb91f">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="saml samlp xenc xs"/>
</Transform>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>bSqD69uUzX0swY6hAKkzLEaWJeMyV2UIoyFBTxLhHi0=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>AiyK11or3hAGSnHADidHKp2XCcH0amBaU8xA6xQrxgKNZBqaKFF0rdbiRdVp4YFbqlQeCruYAEbT1JnAAwRyKLn6IZOJIP7iA3PeSr8bguus58+LGmb30YsYcbpAMxLjhQbmAu1t25v4huaOViZQwNAafkdjKAyhJRa7P8ihEBbl4CUQjYJ0eIASxWZuD6j1tg4afMv9GH809lFGl7KRER8oUp9P6VF5xdJbavpX623eRZRAeqV++CBXKTrFUnMOHrp1eI68IaobKOx/xkN59FX7SabdqpIVE+L9rnPtYYwG0LLpqmAOaSZEhmGKp2y27OA1ZxJZittwFMTmWmtoqA==</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>{removed}</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
<SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>{removed}</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</KeyDescriptor>
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://{my-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/samlp/sso/logout" ResponseLocation="https://{my-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/samlp/sso/logout/response"/>
<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
<AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://{my-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{my-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
</SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points:

Subject contains a NameID element, which represents the authenticated user. The NameID value is a targeted identifier that is directed only to the service provider that is the audience for the token. It is persistent - it can be revoked, but is never reassigned.

[nameidpolicys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#nameidpolicy) element requests a particular name ID format in the response
*ex:*

```
<NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"/>
```

- The Format attribute can have only one of the following values;
  Persistent, emailAddress, unspecified, transient
- For `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent` : Azure
  Active Directory issues the NameID claim as a pairwise identifier.
- For `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient`: Azure Active
  Directory issues the NameID claim as a ***randomly generated value*** that
  is unique to the current SSO operation. This means that ***the value is
  temporary and cannot be used to identify the authenticating user.***

But as seen from the configuration that you provided , it seems to be transient:
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
And response has it persistent. Please check with that.

Audience in audience restriction contains a URI that identifies an intended audience. Azure AD sets the value of this element to the value of Issuer element of the AuthnRequest that initiated the sign- on. Please check and [Configure Azure Active Directory B2C as a SAML IdP to your applications | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-b2c-as-a-saml-idp-in-your-saml-application)

Conditions element specifies conditions that define the acceptable use of SAML assertions.Please check the allowed audience is valid.

**References:**

1. [using-azure-ad-b2c-as-a-saml-idp-with-the-sp-initiated-flow(medium.com)](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-azure-ad-b2c-as-a-saml-idp-with-the-sp-initiated-flow-f4e34356635d)
2. [audience restriction and proxy restriction-saml-core-2.0-os.pdf](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've exchanged from transient to persistent as you suggested, the result is still the same: "The service provider is not a valid audience of the assertion".

Comment: The Audience of a SAMLResponse must match the Service Provider Entity ID/Issuer.[ref1 ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-the-identifier). Also In the manifest check if accessTokenAcceptedVersion is 2.[ref1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/359709/sso-failed-as-the-audience-url-replaced-with-spn-v.html)

Comment: I don't see accessTokenAcceptedVersion in the Metadata but the tag "<saml2p:Response has the attributes: Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">.  And the ID - yeah, where in the response do I see it? Cause yes - I guessed it when writing the meta data. Its a nevis on prem if that helps.

Comment: accessTokenAcceptedVersion is present in the manifest in azure portal

Comment: "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2 is set for the ClientApp and the FrameworkApp. The Framework App, I just corrected. The Error keeps the same. I still have no Idea how to check the ID/Issuer.ref1 ms doc?